# Flutter Hot Reload in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I firstly wondered how to perform a hot reload  in **Flutter** with Android Studio. Since I *am already so used to the auto-save of **Android Studio*** I did not even consider <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> for the hot reload.

I then assigned the `Flutter Hot Reload` in the Keymap and this worked really well. But now I just realised that <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> does *also* perform the hot reload. I looked the shortcut up in the Keymap and discovered that <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> is mapped to `Save All`.

[image: Save All in Keymap]

Now I am wondering what does `Save All` even do and does it do any extra compared to my assigned `Flutter Hot Reload` key combination?
I do not get the reason for `Save All` when Android Studio already saves everything automatically.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Conclusion

It really does matter. Apparrently the Flutter plugin simply reacts to a `Save All` call by executing `Apply Changes`, which will always call `Flutter Hot Reload`.

An interesting observation I made is that `Flutter Hot Reload` will not (as of writing) hot reload the application when there was no change in code, but `Save All` will and `Apply Changes` as well, which is why I wrote that `Save All` calls `Apply Changes`.

Answer (score 11):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> is to save and when "Perform hot reload on save" is enabled also "hot reload"

[image]

Comment: Thank you for that. But why does it then not hot reload when automatic synchronization is enabled?

Comment: I'm confused.  Your original question dors not seem to contain anything about hot reload **not** working.

Comment: I mean, why does it not automatically hot reload. Android Studio automatically saves the files. This was not in the oq.

Comment: I think I understand the question now. It does hot reload by default when you save. Do you get any console output in the debug view in AS?

Comment: No. Sorry for confusing you. I have no problem at all. I am just wondering why the `Save All` function triggers a hot reload, but not automatically because files are saved without pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>.

Comment: So "Save All" triggers hot release but Ctrl+s does not?

Comment: `CTRL + S` triggers the Save All function. I think this question of me was senseless. Android Studio saves files automatically so you will never use `CTRL + S` outside of Flutter and I was wondering why it does not trigger hot reload on auto save, but that is not a good question.

Comment: For all those who have issues with Hot Reload on Android Studio 3.5 check this: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Workarounds-for-common-issues#hot-reload-not-working

Answer (score 2):

Write `flutter run` into the terminal present at below in android studio.
Once the app runs into your device or emulator press `r` into the terminal ->This will hot reload your app [for eg:- make some minor changes into your app after executing the `flutter run` then press `r` you can notice **HOT RELOAD FUNCTIONALITY**

Comment: For which translation tool are you talking?

Answer (score 1):

In my scenario I was writing the code from scratch and not following the coding std. 
  Until then it was problem in Hot reload when I start working on

```
 void main() => runApp(new HelloFlutterApp());
```